# Creating my own flow control statements in C++. Is that acceptable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I always considered `switch` statement as somehow defective:

- works only on integral types and enumerations.
- isn't an readability improvement over traditional if/else chain.
- forget a `break` - you have a bug.
- variable declaration spills over neighbouring cases.
- is essentially a computed goto

Because of said reasons, and also as an exercise on lambdas and variadic templates I created my own flow control function.

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

template<typename V>
bool switch_on(const V& value)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename V, typename P, typename... Args>
bool switch_on(const V& value, const P& p, Args... args)
{
    if(std::get<0>(p)(value, std::get<1>(p)))
    {
        std::get<2>(p)();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return switch_on(value, args...);
    }
}

template<template <typename> class P, typename F, typename V >
auto case_of(const V& v, const F& p) -> decltype( std::make_tuple(P<V>(), v, p) )
{
    return std::make_tuple(P<V>(), v, p);
}

template<typename P, typename F, typename V >
auto case_of(const V& v, const F& p) -> decltype( std::make_tuple(P(), v, p) )
{
    return std::make_tuple(P(), v, p);
}

template<typename F, typename V >
auto case_of(const V& v, const F& p) -> decltype( std::make_tuple(std::equal_to<V>(), v, p) )
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::equal_to<V>(), v, p);
}
```

so I can use:

```
using std::less;
using std::greater;

int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    switch_on(a,
        case_of<less>(0, [&]{
            std::cout << "LESS THAN ZEROOOOOOOOOOOOOO."; 
        }),
        case_of(42, [&]{
            std::cout << "Yes";
        }),
        case_of<greater>(9000, [&]{
            std::cout << "IT'S OVER NINE THOUSAAAAAAAAND!!!";
        })
    );
}
```

While in Lisp, it is encouraged to create new forms of flow control, what about C++? I would also like to see some opinions about template usage, some pointers on how to improve the code and possible corner cases when this code will break.

Comment: Not sure I agree wiht: `isn't an readability improvement over traditional if/else chain.` or `forget a break - you have a bug` lot of functionality for fall through and when you do need it the compiler will warn you about it being missing so not a real problem. Don't believe this is true `variable declaration spills over neighboring cases` in C++. Anything with a constructor is bound into a case scope. Though true `is essentially a computed goto` you can use the same argument for `for(;;)`, `while()`, `if(){}else{}` etc. Any control flow basically boils down to a computed goto.

Comment: @LokiAstari `when you do need it the compiler will warn you about it being missing so not a real problem`. Not sure what you mean here - can compiler distinguish when I need fall-through? `Anything with a constructor is bound into a case scope.` [Well, apparently only if you use braces to introduce one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/92730/1012936), that is, by `is essentially a computed goto` I meant `goto` not on assembler level, but on a high-level language level. And the rant against `break` is because `switch` favours less common case (I want to fall-throgh) over more common case.

Comment: @LokiAstari I realise that my approach is flawed though - this function doesn't integrate so well with language, but I'm still looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lisp has an uniform syntax, so it’s possible to create user defined flow control constructs that look exactly like the built in constructs. In C++, that’s generally not possible.

Your code is certainly clever, and it solves the problem of omitted breaks (I consider the other drawbacks you list less important). However:

- Despite naming this a “switch”, you’ve essentially recreated an if-else chain. Notably, a compiler may have a bit more difficulty optimizing this than a traditional switch.
- Your implementation does not seem to support range comparisons or a default case, although both of these seem to be doable in your conceptual framework.
- When used in a disciplined way, falling through from one switch case to the next is not always devoid of merit.
- I’m not sure that returning this boolean has a great benefit. It might be preferable to design a construct that ensures that one of the cases is always executed.
- Be honest: do you really find this more readable than a traditional switch statement?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Well, at first I tried to copy Pascal's `case of` statement, and halfway switched to VB's `Select Case`. So... yeah, maybe it's not that readable.